# jquery ajax data array from php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

heres my code so you see what i'm trying to do, which obviously isn't working:

```
        $('#selector').change(function() {  
        if ($(this).val().length > 0)
        {           
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: "id="+$(this).val(),
                success: function(data){
                    if (data != 'error')
                    {
                        $('#main_url').val(data[2]);
                        $('#main_url_title').val(data[3]);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

i set up an alert(data); and all it pops up with is "Array". so now my 2 fields are being populated with "r" and "a"...what is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: The string literal "Array" means that you stringified an array on the PHP side of things.  Can we see your PHP code, please?

Comment: $sql = mysql_query("select * from `table` where `id`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id'])."'");

if (mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0)
{
 echo 'error';
}
else
{
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
 {
  foreach ($row as $k => $v)
   $data[] = $v;
 }
 
 echo $data;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may encode php array in json data, and then use json with jquery

Add in ajax.php something like `echo json_encode($your_php_array)`

Comment: well i know i could always just implode the array via php and then use the split function...just wondering if there was a better way of doing this....

Comment: this seems good but now i need a hand with using the json encoded array within the javascript.