# Pass array in jQuery ajax

Tags: php, jquery

My imaginery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sub").click(function() {
        info['moto']  = $("#moto").val();
        info['motox'] = $("#motox").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "index.php",
            data: "arr="+info,
            success: function(msg){
                $('.answer').html(msg);
            }
        })
    })
})
```

How could I make, that after receiving it in .php file I could use POST method like this: `$_POST['moto']` and `$_POST['motox']` or something like that? What should I change? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just:

```
data: info,
```

(And you need to initialize info as an object in the first place: `var info = {}`)

Answer (score 1):

Check out jQuery [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/), it does all the work for you if you are working with form inputs.

Comment: serialize is nice but i found it make more work when dealing with degradation

Answer (score 0):

I thinkyoushould go also the same way like [jquery-ajax-data-array-from-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413096/jquery-ajax-data-array-from-php)