# jQuery get all values of multiple select, not only selected

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to submit a whole multiple select (which is $('#tags_selected')) via Ajax

```
$.ajax({
  url: base_url + 'companies/editTagsAsync',
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: $('#tags_selected').val(),
  success: function (json) {
    console.log(json);
  }
});
```

But it only sends the values that are selected. I want to pass ALL the values in the selectbox. There's probably an easy solution to this, but I just don't know it...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767279/pass-array-in-jquery-ajax you have to pass array as you want to send multiple values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can push all your select value into an array and send it through `data`:

```
var selectArr = []; 

$('#tags_selected option').each(function() {
    selectArr.push($(this).val());
});

$.ajax({
  url: base_url + 'companies/editTagsAsync',
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: selectArr,
  success: function (json) {
    console.log(json);
  }
});
```

Comment: This worked! I had to change it to `data: { tags_selected: selectArr }` and then it worked perfectly. Thank you :)

Comment: This worked.
but if you want to get the selected values only, you can use $('#tags_selected').val();

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the `<option>` descendants of the dropdown and get their values:

```
data: { 
  values: $('#tags_selected').find("option").map(function() {return this.value;})
}
```

This way on the server side you will get an array named "values" with all the values. I have used `.find()` instead of `.children()` to get the options in anticipation of the drop down containing `<optgroup>` elements.

Comment: This returned a error... Not enough arguments. Thank you for your answer, though!

Comment: @JobertEnamno: Slower than what?

Comment: @PatrickManser: I am entirely unsure what error you are referring to.

Comment: @Jon It just said "Not enough arguments" :/

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to send both selected and all values array.

var data: { 
        allValues: $('#tags_selected').find("option").map(function() {return this.value;}),
        selectedValues :$('#tags_selected').val()
    }
var data={ }
$.ajax({
  url: base_url + 'companies/editTagsAsync',
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: function (json) {
    console.log(json);
  }
});
```